# 1D K-means implementation with GPU support

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pytorch

I know there are polynomial-time solutions for the global optimum of k-means in 1D (e.g. [kmeans1d](https://www.dannyadam.com/blog/2019/07/kmeans1d-globally-optimal-efficient-1d-k-means/)), but they're usually implemented with dynamic programming in C++. I need a 1D k-means solution for PyTorch so I can utilize CUDA acceleration. Just using an existing library for multidimensional k-means (scikit-learn, kmeans_pytorch, etc.) with `dim=1` isn't optimal because of the random initialization and it fails to solve problems as simple as:

```py
any_kmeans_library([1., 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], k=4) # expected centroids: [1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 7.5]
```

Do you know of an implementation that allows this and/or a code snippet of yours that can achieve it?

Comment: I wouldn't say k-means fails in the above case, maybe fails to achieve the desired result but the algorithm executes correctly; global optimality is never guaranteed with k means

Comment: @DerekG, yes. There are 1D solutions that find the global optimum, though. So for the 1D case specifically k-means doesn't fail, there's just a way to do it more optimally.